# LibGDX - Mapping Individual Textures to each face of a cylinder

Tags: object, 3d, libgdx, textures, render

I'm trying to create a 3D coin object (from a cylinder) which should have a different texture for each side (up/down)

How can I do this? Or at least, how can I simulate it?

I could combine two cylinders to render different textures, but is this the correct approach?

Comment: Set the last `close` argument of `CylinderShapeBuilder` to `false` and then use `EllipseShapeBuilder` to close the cylinder yourself. The code is open, so you can easily copy it: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/shapebuilders/CylinderShapeBuilder.java#L73-L78. With that said, it looks like you want look into using a modeling application instead, because building models by code can get messy really fast.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Xoppa I follow your tutorials (for 3d) it's very useful.